# Command terminated with an exception

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Everytime I try to create a Grails project, I get the following error. I can create a project from terminal but not from IDE. I'm using GGTS and I'm new to Grails.

> Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see
>   details for partial output) Command: GrailsCommand(P/BookSolution>
>   compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies)
>   ---- System.out ---- Loading Grails 2.3.8 . |Environment set to development .......... |Compiling 78 source files .Error  |
>   Compilation error: startup failed:
>   C:\grails\BookSolution\target\work\plugins\database-migration-1.4.0\grails-app\controllers\grails\plugin\databasemigration\DbdocController.groovy:
>   -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class
>   'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.  @ line -1, column
>   -1. C:\grails\BookSolution\target\work\plugins\database-migration-1.4.0\grails-app\controllers\grails\plugin\databasemigration\DbdocController.groovy:
>   -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class
>   'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.  @ line -1, column
>   -1. 2 errors Error | org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException Error |   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   Error |   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   Error |   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   Error |   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)   ...
>   68 more
>   ------System.err:-----------

Comment: the error is related to database-migration-1.4.0 -I can confirm as part of grails 2.4 in ide this plugin is by default added to BuildConfig and has not given me any issues so far... try commenting it out ? refresh-dependencies ?

Comment: I don't think the error is really related to database-migration.  I expect the problem will happen with all controllers.  See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - not even gone down 1.8 route as yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using Java 8.  Grails 2.3.8 does not support Java 8.  If you want to use Java 8 you need to upgrade to the Grails 2.4.  As of right now the latest in that release chain is 2.4.2.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java 8. I updated to Grails 2.4.2 and the errors are gone now. But new error appeared. Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'BookSolution'.
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.count(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Number;. What does this means?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the code.  First guess is that you have code in the project that was compiled with the other version of Grails and Groovy.  Do a full clean and/or find if you can reproduce the problem with a clean project.  If the problem persists, post a separate question here on SO as not to muddy this question for folks who find it while searching for "receptive method" or the like.  I think the solution to this one is resolved now.

Comment: Found the solution for build error. It was due to compiler mismatch. Thanks everyone for your time.